# Help with Indigenous characters (unicode)

Tags: unicode, languages

I am writing a document in `LaTeX` and would like to be able to write out Indigenous names correctly. Examples are shown below.

[image]

I often use this website for help which allows me to copy and paste into other applications: https://denefont.com/utilities/web-key/  Is there any way to do this in LaTeX? I don't have to use any special document type or class, or any particular packages or other special formatting. The website above states:

> Good News: You don’t need to download any special fonts.  The versions of Arial, Times New Roman, Calibri, Cambria, and Tahoma fonts on newer computers are Unicode; and they contain all the special characters used by the Dene Languages.  All you need is some special keyboard software to type the Dene characters. That’s what Unicode Dene Keyboards are all about.

So, I tried this, which *almost* works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{texgyretermes-regular.otf}
\begin{document}

Délı̨ne

Łı́ı́dlı̨ı̨ Kų́ę́

\end{document}
```

It produces this:

[image]

Notice the missing "accents" below the "i" and "e" in Deline and below the double "i" at the end of Liidlii.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use the command line tool `albatross ı̨` to get a list of fonts which include it (or try one of the fonts the website tells you to use)

Comment: on my system `\setmainfont{Noto Sans Regular}` works (found with albatross ...). Times New Roman doesn't, but Cambria works too.

Comment: Btw, the problem is only the `ı̨`, not the `ę` (you just happened to mis-spell "Délı̨n**ę**" in the input)

Comment: Note that `ı̨`, `ų́` and `ę́` are not encoded as single codepoints in Unicode but consist of two (or three) codepoints. This might or might not be relevant when looking for a font that supports them.